# How to adjust the position of the x-axis ticks and put the angle degree on the values ​of the x-axis ticks in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

Dears, I have the following plot in Matlab as shown below:

[image]

The x-axis represents angles. I would like to **add the angle degree**, which is the small circle on the x-axis ticks, and I need to **distribute the values ​​of the x-axis elegantly**, not, as shown above, they are close to each other. Any assistance, please?

```
VEC_MIS = [0.238000000000000.1.18980000000000.2.14160000000000.4.997000000,000.6.90070000000000.10.70790000000.14.5152000000,000.16.89470000,000.23.31950000000000
Vec_BEAM = [113.265900000000,117.549100000000,117.549100000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000,117.787000000000];
Vec_NOBEAM = [0.238000000000000,1.18980000000000,2.14160000000000,4.99700000000000,4.99700000000000,8.80430000000000,10.7079000000000,14.5152000000000,16.4188000000000,19.2742000000000,21.1779000000000,23.5574000000000];
ThetaHalf = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60];
figure
semilogx(ThetaHalf,Vec_BEAM, '-dg' ,ThetaHalf,Vec_NOBEAM, '-^r' ,ThetaHalf,Vec_MIS, '-Oc' , 'LineWidth' ,2, 'MarkerEdgeColor' , 'b' )
xticks(ThetaHalf)
xlabel( '\theta_1_/_2' );
ylabel( 'Coverage area m^2' );
legend( 'With Beam' , 'Without Beam' , 'Manual' )
grid on ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the degree symbol to each of the xticks then you simply need to specify the "degrees" format for the xticks using the following command;

```
xtickformat("degrees");
```

[More on the xtickformat function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xtickformat.html?searchHighlight=xtickformat&s_tid=srchtitle_xtickformat_1)

As for changing the distance between xticks, there isn't an easy way to do so that I know of. I know of two options, one is to change the angle of the xticks so that they overlap less using the xtickangle function;

```
xtickangle(angle);
```

[More on the xtickangle function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xtickangle.html)

The other way is to specify the xticks in order to avoid overlapping xticks, this can be done using the xticks function;

```
xticks([Point1, Point2, Point3, ...]);
```

[More on the xticks function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticks.html)